# Why am I getting 'No matching constructor error' in C++ code?

Tags: c++

I began studying C++ recently, using emacs with lsp mode. I have these errors in the code:

- No matching constructor for initialization of 'Student[5]'
- 'Student' does not refer to a value

Can't figure out what the problem is...

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#define STUDENT_ARRAY_SIZE 5

typedef struct Date
{
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
} date;

date parse_date (const std::string &date_string)
{
  date input;
  std::istringstream stream(date_string);
  char delimeter = '/';
  stream >> input.day >> delimeter >> input.month >> delimeter >> input.year;
  return input;
};

typedef struct FullName
{
  std::string name;
  std::string surname;
  std::string secondary_name;
} full_name;

full_name parse_name (const std::string &name_string)
{
  full_name input;
  std::istringstream stream(name_string);
  char delimeter = ' ';
  stream >> input.name >> delimeter  >> input.surname >> input.secondary_name;
  return input;
}

class Student
{
  private:
  
  full_name name;
  date birth_day;
  std::string telephone_number;
  std::string address;
  std::string faculty;
  int course;
  
  public:

   // Constructor
     Student(full_name name, date birth_day, std::string
     telephone_number, std::string address, std::string faculty, int
     course)
     {
       this->name = name;
       this->birth_day = birth_day;
       this->telephone_number = telephone_number;
       this->address = address;
       this->faculty = faculty;
       this->course = course;
     }
     
     // Getter methods
     full_name getFullName()
     {
       return name;
     }
     
     date getBirthDay()
     {
       return birth_day;
     }
     
     std::string getTelephoneNumber()
     {
       return telephone_number;
     }
     
     std::string getAddress()
     {
       return address;
     }
     
     std::string getFaculty()
     {
       return faculty;
     }
     
     int getCourse()
     {
       return course;
     }
     
     // Setter methods
     void setFullName(full_name name)
     {
       this->name = name;
     }
     
     void setBirthDay(date birth_day)
     {
       this->birth_day = birth_day;
     }
     
     void setTelephoneNumber(std::string telephone_number)
     {
       this->telephone_number = telephone_number;
     }
     
     void setAddress(std::string address)
     {
       this->address = address;
     }
     
     void setFaculty(std::string faculty)
     {
       this->faculty = faculty;
     }
     
     void setCourse(int course)
     {
       this->course = course;
     }

  void show();
};

 void Student::show()
   {
     std::cout << "Name: " << name.name << " " << name.surname << " "
     << name.secondary_name << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Birthday: " << birth_day.day << "/" <<
     birth_day.month << "/" << birth_day.year << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Phone Number: " << telephone_number << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Address: " << address << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Faculty: " << faculty << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Course: " << course << std::endl;
   }

int
main (void)
{ 
  Student *db = new Student[STUDENT_ARRAY_SIZE];

  db[0] = Student student(parse_name("Name Surname SecondaryName"),
     parse_date("12/04/2003"), "+123123123", "Sporty street 8",
     "MMF", 3);

  delete[] db;

  return 0;
}
```

Tried using all my knowledge and gdb but no success. Expecting your suggestions on how to make it work and also on how to make it better.

Comment: In the future, don't write so much code before checking if it behaves as you expect.

Comment: Which textbook were you "studying C++" from, where you picked up sample code like `typedef struct Date ... date`? You should immediately throw it away and get a real C++ textbook, that actually teaches C++, and not C. That kind of a construct is only used in C, and is utterly meaningless in C++.

Comment: And the `Student`'s constructor also suggests low quality and sub standard C++ instructional material. All quality C++ textbooks will explain how to use member initialization syntax to correctly implement that constructor, instead of that kind of "useless use of `this`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
Student *db = new Student[STUDENT_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

this is constructing (and initializing) an array of 5 students, it has to call their default constructor (one with no arguments). you didn't define a default constructor, so you should define one, it should either initialize the members with default values or just default it to "do nothing special" by setting it equal to `default`, which default constructs the members. (constructs empty strings)

```cpp
class Student
{
...
public:
Student() = default;
...
}
```